# PDFCreator and Ghostscript for Windows - is it possible to monitor progress?

Tags: windows, pdf-generation, ghostscript

I'm using PDFCreator Free, which uses Ghostscript (gswin32c.exe) behind the scenes to produce PDF files by printing to a virtual printer. I'm using it in batch mode, which generates the PDF, then launches a custom batch file.

Some large files take several minutes to complete, during which time there is no way to determine progress (my batch file doesn't launch until the process is done).  I can see the gswin32c.exe file running in Task Manager, and in the %Temp%/PDFCreator directory, the Spool and Temp directories get some content.

Is there a way to determine Ghostscript's progress (or at least the number of pages already generated) so I can report this from somewhere?  I can't see or change the command-line arguments sent to Ghostscript, since it's called from the proprietary PDFCreator software.  Is there a file somewhere that contains some type of status or metrics on the running GS process?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, no. It depends slightly on the exact command-line arguments (which you haven't given), but I imagine all the feedback is being suppressed.

Note that pdfwrite doesn't create **any** pages at all until its finished processing the input, and there's no easy way to determine how many pages are in the input PostScript program.

Comment: Edited my question to include the fact that I can't see the command line arguments being sent to ghostscript.

Comment: Well, it claims to be open source, so presumably you could download it and build it yourself, and that would let you see the arguments being used.

Comment: The source code can be downloaded here https://github.com/pdfforge/PDFCreator so you can look and see how its called, and you can potentially modify it yourself.